# A pair of questions about isomorphism between two posets.

Tags: induction, relations

> Theorem: Let $P = (X, \le)$ be a finite total order containing n elements. Let $Q = (\{1, 2, \ldots , n\}, \le')$. Then $P \cong Q$.

I have a few questions about the proof of this theorem. In my book it's done by induction. Do the $2$ quotes below contradict each other?

> We assume that the result is true for $n = k \ldots$

For starters, template for proving induction is to prove $p(n) \to p(n + 1) $ for all $n$ starting at base case, right? Does the quote above mean $p(n)$ is defined to be $P \cong Q$ and assumed to be true?

Right after that quote comes this sentence:

> $\ldots$ and suppose $P$ is a total order on $k + 1$ elements. Let $Q = (\{1, 2, \ldots, k + 1\}, \le')$ . We must show that $P \cong Q$.

To me it sounds like they are assuming $p(n + 1)$ and proving $p(n)$. Is that right?

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you'd think that.

Comment: @ Asaf Karagila, can you tell me what's here $p(n)$ and what's $p(n + 1)$, please?

Comment: To me it sounds like they're assuming $p(k)$ and proving $p(k+1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let
$$p(n)=\mbox{ for all total orders }P\mbox{ with }n\mbox{ elements, }P\simeq Q=(\{1,2,\ldots,n\},\leq')$$
If the base case is not specified, the proof is technically incomplete, but in this case we can take the base case to be either $0$ or $1$ and in either case the total order is trivial because there are fewer than two elements, so the base case is true.

The author is setting up the situation to prove $p(1)\wedge p(2)\wedge \ldots\wedge p(n)\Rightarrow p(n+1)$; the assumption is that $p(i)$ is true for all $i\leq n$, we suppose that $P$ is a total order with $n+1$ elements, and we want to show that $P\simeq Q=(\{1,2,\ldots,n+1\},\leq')$, which is $p(n+1)$. This form of an induction proof is valid and equivalent to all other forms of induction.

Comment: I am having hard time understanding why we assume $P$ has $n + 1$ elements when $p(n)$ says $P$ is a total order with $n$ elements.

Comment: We already know that $p(n)$ is true at that point, so we do not need to consider the case where $P$ has $n$ elements unless it comes up in the proof for $n+1$. We are trying to show that $p(n+1)$ is true, in which case we need to show that a poset with $n+1$ elements is isomorphic to $(\{1,2,\ldots,n+1\},\leq')$. If we assume the poset has $n$ elements, there's nothing we need to prove because it has already been done.

Comment: So, are we, in effect, proving $p(n + 1) \to p(n + 1)$? When is this kind of induction used?

Comment: It's simply not $p(n+1)\to p(n+1)$, it's $p(n)\to p(n+1)$. I suggest you read more induction proofs than just this one to help you understand it better. This is a very common strategy.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it now. I thought we can use **only** $p(1)$ through $p(n)$ as assumptions and directly proceed to proving $p(n + 1)$ without any other assumptions. It's more like $p(n + 1)$ is its own proof where we can start off assuming $P$ has $n + 1$ elements and prove that fact by the end of $p(n + 1)$. So long as we use $p(1)$ through $p(n)$ in the body of $p(n + 1)$ inductive step holds. In that sense, assumptions $p(1)$ through $p(n)$ are just additional aid when proving $p(n + 1)$.

Answer (score 1):

In your case $p(n)$ is the assumption that every total order on $n$ elements is isomorphic to $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ with the usual ordering.

The proof then assumes that $p(k)$ holds, and then should proceed to prove that $p(k+1)$ holds as well. Usually this is done by removing the maximal (or minimal) element and using the induction hypothesis.

This is one of these places where using different letters for stating the hypothesis, and when proceeding with the induction step might be helpful. Namely, we state $p(n)$ using $n$ as a variable, then we say "Assume $p(k)$, we'll show that $p(k+1)$ holds as well."